# UIButton does not change its alpha while being pushed

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, uibutton, alpha

I am programming a game with a end screen. It's a view with a UIImageView on it.

The imageView has a UIVisualEffectView additionaly.

There is a button on my end screen (No, it's not part of the imageView).

If you touch it, it won't change it's alpha, like usual.

Comment: Is the button's action being triggered properly?

Comment: Yes, it calls the method

Comment: Is the button's type set to "Custom" by any chance? Only a "System" button changes visually when pressed (by default).

Comment: Yes, it is a System Button

Comment: Have you tried setting the `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` and `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` properties on the button?

Comment: No, but I want the default effect for System Buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to initialize your button with UIButton(type:) and .System as type. Something like this:

```
var button = UIButton(type: .System)
```

If you don't use this, your button will not change it's alpha while being pushed.